# Spring portlet and Liferay portlet are they same or different?

Tags: spring, liferay

I'm curious to know that if Spring portlet and Liferay portlet are they same or different?.

Answer (score 0):

As wikipedia says [Portlet Specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Portlet_Specification) portlets are a contract between the portlet and a portlet container. Portlets have been defined in JSR-286 The Java Portlet Specification.
So from this point your question can be answered with: yes they are the same, because they both fulfill the portlet specification.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing info @PowerStat. That's really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are frameworks respecting portlet specifications JSR-286. They are used to develop applications in a portal container. Liferay offers also some useful portlets (open source) developed on their framework. So, for a developer it is up to you to choose if you would like to use Liferay MVC portlet or Spring MVC one. It depends on your familiarity with them (for example, if you have already worked on spring mvc, it would be more simple/easy for you to implement portlet, except some minus differences relative to portlet context).

Comment: Thank you @javaxiss. I'll definitely check on that.